# Alternatives to Dynamic JsonParsing

Tags: c#, dynamic, aws-lambda, jsonserializer

I am using aws lambda's api request template to create and call post methods. I have to send a post body from my code, which should be json serialized.

Here is a way I am doing it now:

```
**dynamic pObj = new JObject();
pObj.Url = DownloadURL;
pObj.Name = IName;
pObj.ID = I.ID;**

 Custom redirect = new Custom()
 {
     url = new Uri(lambdaEndpoint),
     **Body = pObj.ToString(),**
     Method = "POST",
     Available = true
 };
```

But I read an [article](http://www.dotnetperls.com/dynamic) where it talks about performance issues with using dynamic keyword.

Is there an alternative approach of doing this that is better in performance? Any help will be appreciated.

Thanks

Comment: If "Body" is accepting pain text ... you can always manually build the json string with no need to create dynamic object just to deserialize it

Comment: Can you share your json?

Comment: @aloisdg My json is very simple: here it is.                                                    {                                                                                                        "Url":"xyz.com",                                                                                 "Name":"abc",                                                                                               "ID":"123"                                                                                                                 }

Answer (score 0):

An alternative to the usage of `dynamic` would be a direct deserialization. Since you know your object, it should fit as expected.

[Demo](https://dotnetfiddle.net/0fZhIG)

```
    using System;
    using Newtonsoft.Json;


    public class Program
    {
        // create you class. You can generate it with http://json2csharp.com/ or use Visual Studio (edit>past special)
        public class Custom
        {
            public string Url { get; set; }
            public string Name { get; set; }
            public string Id { get; set; }
        }

        public void Main()
        {
            string json = "{ \"Url\":\"xyz.com\", \"Name\":\"abc\", \"ID\":\"123\" }";
            // the magic code is here! Go to http://www.newtonsoft.com/json for more information
            Custom custom = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Custom>(json);

            // custom is fill with your json!
            Console.WriteLine(custom.Name);
        }
    }
```

output:

```
abc
```